# how to center sprite image and text?

Tags: html, css

I am using css sprites. I have a simple image and a text. I want to display the image in center of the page and the text to vertically center to that image. I am new to css, I couldn't find a way to do it.

The code I have is

```
<div class="sprite"></div>hi


.sprite {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define `background` `position` and **one** `div`  **as like this**

**Css**

```
   .centerText{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.sprite {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png") 3px -6px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="centerText">
<div class="sprite"></div>hi
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2dLA/1/)**